# Find out what percentage of a pdf page is content with itext

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

How do I know using itext how much of a page is text? ie does the text take up 50% of the whole page? or 25%? is there a way you can get the Y co-ordinate of where the text finishes? So then you know where to write the next bit of text to.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not trivial.
But the easiest implementation (which makes a lot of assumptions) goes a little bit like this:

```
class TextMeasurementListener implements IEventListener {

    private float space = 0.0f;

    public TextMeasurementListener(PdfDocument pdfDocument, int pageNr)
    {
        new PdfDocumentContentParser(pdfDocument).processContent(pageNr, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if(type != EventType.RENDER_TEXT)
            return;

        TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;
        for(TextRenderInfo charInfo : textRenderInfo.getCharacterRenderInfos())
        {
            CharacterRenderInfo characterRenderInfo = new CharacterRenderInfo(charInfo);
            space += characterRenderInfo.getBoundingBox().getWidth() * characterRenderInfo.getBoundingBox().getHeight();
        }
    }

    public float getReservedSpaceInPoints()
    {
        return space;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method essentially processes a single page, and counts the area of each bounding box of each character.

Comment: I think Luke means something more trivial, the topmost y coordinate for which all content is still above or at it, i.e. the bottommost y coordinate of any piece of content.

Comment: Ah this is looking very good! But what you are calling space is essentially the number of characters on the page? it counts every character? I have a large page that is gives 119883.600 so this is almost a full page.

Comment: It loops over every character, and adds the area (that's the getWidth() * getHeight() part) to the variable `space`.

Comment: So a character is a boundingBox?

Comment: A character **has** a boundingbox